# The subpane for any modifier does not appear in my version of Blender

Tags: modifiers

I am new and novice at Blender (version 2.79 under Mac OS 10.11.6 El Capitan).
I am just trying to intersect a cube and a cylinder. I get them to overlap, select the cylinder then I hit the spacebar to get to Add modifier. I select Boolean and ...nothing happens.
No subpanel with information or asking to click on the cube. Nowhere to decide what boolean operation to perform.

I lost half a day looking on line for tutorials, but got nowhere. I suspect this is a bug.
Can anyone help me ?
Thank you
Alain

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Your Modifier properties will be under this tab.

Comment: Ray,  Thank you for your answer.   However, I do not see a window like the one in your picture. I would like to show a view of what I see but do not know how to add a screen copy I have made.  Could you tell me how to do that on this list?